# Servlet pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My DispatcherServlets:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>get</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>get</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/get/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

All request are delegate to first Controller. I want to create two servlets,

1. With request like `localhost:8080/myapp/myrequest`
2. Request like `localhost:8080/myapp/get/something`

What patterns i must set?

Comment: Why do you have two servlets in the first place, and not just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern

```
<url-pattern>/get/</url-pattern>
```

handles only requests to

```
.../get/
```

it won't handle

```
.../get/something/else
```

It looks for an exact match.

The pattern

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

is special and matches everything that hasn't been matched.

In other words, if you want the second servlet to match everything starting with `/get`, change it to

```
<url-pattern>/get/*</url-pattern>
```

In my opinion, this doesn't make much sense as a `DispatcherServlet` should be the single point of entry into an app. You should instead modify your controllers appropriately.

Comment: In general you want a single `DispatcherServlet` but there are situations in which you want different configurations and as such have multiple `DispatcherServlet` instances. (This is also the reason why the `ContextLoaderListener`s context serves as a parent).

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>users</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

for this block of code you need to give the request as,

```
localhost:8080/myapp/myrequest<br>
localhost:8080/myapp/orWhatever
```

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>get</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>get</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/get/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

for this block of code you need to give the request as,
`localhost:8080/myapp/get` 
only